# Java: Filtering lots of data

Tags: java, filtering, bigdata

I have ~10M rows of data, each containing ~1000 columns (String & Numeric). What I need is to be able to apply simple filters (>, <, RANGE, ==) to this data set as quick as possible (less than a second to get 10K slice for this data).

What kind of production ready technology, which could be used from Java exist?

Comment: Relational databases come to mind.

Comment: You're perhaps fishing for Hadoop HBase, even though 10m rows isn't nearly "Big Data" :-/

Comment: If you are using Java8, there is an option to go with parallel streams https://www.airpair.com/java/posts/parallel-processing-of-io-based-data-with-java-streams

Answer (score 0):

Where is your data coming from?  This sounds like a task for a database.

Comment: Database allows to apply much more complex filters and amend data in parallel. Here we can ensure, that data is fed by a single thead (preload let's say).

Answer (score 0):

A sql database with an index on the fields you're filtering. The index can be based on numeric value, which will make range and equals queries pretty quick.

Comment: Not good - too much memory and low performance for lots of parallel queries.

Comment: @Denis I don't see you mention issues with parallel queries in the question, or any of your existing insights into the performance of DBs. You are needlessly letting people second-guess you.

Comment: Denis - I would argue that a SQL database would scale better than writing ad-hoc code in Java to do this... for general purpose work. If you want to run this in core Java in core memory, then you should be looking at creating some ordered collections and searching them using the binary search technique, or creating some tree-like collections (Btree) and traversing them. Databases do this out of the box and can be scaled.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not from database,
You can do it in few threads and then combine the results in order to improve performance.

Like, here AMOUNT is a number of elements in your map:

```
package com.stackoverflow.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
public class Test6 {
  private static final int AMOUNT = 10000000;
  private static final int CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
  private static final int PART  = AMOUNT / CORES;
  private static final class MapFilterTask implements Callable<Map<String,Number >> {
    private Integer fromElement;
    private Integer toElement;
    private Map<String,Number > map;
    private MapFilterTask(Map<String,Number > map, Integer fromElement, Integer toElement) {
      this.map=map;
      this.fromElement = fromElement;
      this.toElement = toElement;
    }

    public Map<String,Number > call() throws Exception {
      for(int i=fromElement; i<=toElement; i++){
        //filetr your map and return filtered resutl
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    Map<String,Number > yourMap =new HashMap<String, Number>();
    ExecutorService taskExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CORES);
    List<Callable<Map<String,Number >>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Map<String,Number >>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < CORES; i++) {
      tasks.add(new MapFilterTask(yourMap,i*PART,(i+1)*PART));
    }
    List<Future<Map<String,Number >>> futures = taskExecutor.invokeAll(tasks);
    Map<String,Number > newMap =new HashMap<String, Number>();
    for(Future<Map<String,Number >> feature : futures){
      newMap.putAll(feature.get());
    }
   // Map<String,Numeric>
  }
}
```

And for me it works 4 times faster only with VM args : **-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M**

Without VM args I got 1.7 time increment on my laptop with 4 cores processor and Linux Mint OS.

Comment: You'd need a lot of threads. If it's in memory you would be advised to store it in a structure which is innately searchable - an ordered list can be binary searched much more quickly, for example.

Comment: You don't need more threads than your PC have cores for improving performance, this question was marked as Java so I assume that author has map data structure "(String & Numeric)", but ofc in general it depends on case which structure should be.

Comment: The point is that running through 10million records takes 10 million operations - that needs a lot of CPU ticks. The trick to this would be to index it so the filters don't run through all the records, then you don't need to throw hardware at it.

Comment: Yeah, but we don't know it, it also can be the case if we are getting this map only once from external service , filter it and cache it.

Comment: In this case depending on amount of cores you can increase speed of filtering in ~cores time.

Comment: I admire your attempt to make force this to be a multithreading problem.

Comment: Ashley, and which problem do you think can appear here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65160/discussion-between-ashley-frieze-and-maksym).